# Storing pixel values of a BMP file

Tags: c, struct, pixel, bmp

I'm trying to store the pixel values of a BMP file in a 2D dynamically allocated array of structs but it keeps giving a segmentation fault.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PIXEL{
        unsigned char Red, Green, Blue;
}*pixel;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        //variable declarations and open the file
        FILE* fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (fin == NULL){
                printf("Error opening file.\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        unsigned char info[54];
        int width, height, i, j;

        fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fin);    //read the header
        width = *(int*)&info[18];
        height = *(int*)&info[22];

        pixel **image = (pixel **) malloc(sizeof(pixel *) * width); //reserve enough space for RGB for each pixel
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++){
                image[i] = (pixel *) malloc(sizeof(pixel) * height);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < width; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < height; j++){
                        image[i][j]->Blue = getc(fin);  //put the blue value of the pixel
                        image[i][j]->Green = getc(fin); //green value
                        image[i][j]->Red = getc(fin);   //red value
                        printf("Pixel %d: [%d, %d, %d]\n", (i+1)*(j+1), image[i][j]->Blue, image[i][j]->Green, image[i][j]->Blue);
                }
        }

        fclose(fin);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: the printf line should have image[i][j]->Red instead of image[i][j]->Blue twice

Comment: what line does it give you the error ? Use a nice simple debugger like  visual studio express to step thru your code. Also try dry running the code using a very small 10 by 10 pixel bitmap.

Comment: ah, figured it out it was an error opening the bmp file

Comment: Be careful in the printf. You specify %d format but give unsigned chars. This may be dangerous, add casts to (int) instead

Answer (score 0):

You did not check for valid width and height values from the header. If for any reason they are huge (for instance if the file read failed) this will crash.

Also, %d in printf expects an int. You should cast your unsigned chars to int or it may crash.

Comment: `printf` does not crash when given a `char` for `%d`. The argument is automatically cast to the expected type, and promoting a `char`, unsigned or not, up to `int` should not cause a crash.